# NOTICE: Not enabling PHP 7.3 FPM by default on Apache2 but PHP-FPM is running productive

Tags: php, php-fpm, apache2

My Debian Buster server annoyes me on each upgrade with the following notice:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
...
NOTICE: Not enabling PHP 7.3 FPM by default.
NOTICE: To enable PHP 7.3 FPM in Apache2 do:
NOTICE: a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif
NOTICE: a2enconf php7.3-fpm
NOTICE: You are seeing this message because you have apache2 package installed.
```

But it's enabled and running perfectly:

```
$ sudo a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif
Considering dependency proxy for proxy_fcgi:
Module proxy already enabled
Module proxy_fcgi already enabled
Module setenvif already enabled
$ sudo a2enconf php7.3-fpm
Conf php7.3-fpm already enabled
```

I have already checked for `libapache2-mod-php7.3` but it's not installed.

Answer (score 2):

Seems there was still a remain of `libapache2-mod-php7.3` installed. I noticed this with `dpkg -l | grep libapache2-mod-php`.

Could not remove these remains with `sudo apt remove libapache2-mod-php7.3` but

`sudo apt remove --purge libapache2-mod-php7.3`

did the trick!

Comment: I'm still seeing the notices on `apt upgrade`. What else could case that?